# Add multiple marker on google map v2 using volley

Tags: android, google-maps, android-asynctask, android-maps-v2, android-volley

I know I stand in the right place to ask help about my case study, and then in several day I was thinking about Is it possible to Storing data to MapFragment using Volley Library but unfortunately until now I can't found solution. Generally MapFragment using AsycnTask (if I'm wrong please teach me). why I use Volley Library because full power to get/post data client server. could you kindly give me some clue or implementation how to solve my problem. Thanks in advance

```
public class MapTestFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = MapTestFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String url = "myurl";

    private List<MapEntity> mbList = new ArrayList<MapEntity>();
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    static final LatLng Location = new LatLng(-1.782877, 90.381806);
    Marker mark;
    private MapTestAdapter adapter;
    private HashMap<Marker, MapEntity> mMarkersHashMap;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        getLatLang();
        mMarkersHashMap = new HashMap<Marker, MapEntity>();
        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();
            plotMarkers(mbList);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rootView;
    }

    private void getLatLang() {
        JsonArrayRequest mapReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url, 
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                MapEntity mb = new MapEntity();

                                mb.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                                mb.setLat(((Number) obj.get("lat"))
                                        .doubleValue());
                                mb.setLang(((Number) obj.get("lang"))
                                        .doubleValue());
                                mb.setThumbnail(obj.getString("thumbnail"));

                                mbList.add(mb);

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO: handle exception
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    }
                });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(mapReq);

    }

    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

            if (googleMap != null) {
                googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        marker.showInfoWindow();
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }

    private void plotMarkers(List<MapEntity> mbList)
    {
        if(mbList.size() > 0)
        {
            for (MapEntity myMarker : mbList2)
            {

                // Create user marker with custom icon and other options
                MarkerOptions markerOption = new MarkerOptions().
                        position(new LatLng(myMarker.getLat(), 
                                myMarker.getLang()));
                markerOption.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.
                        fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher));

                Marker currentMarker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOption);
                mMarkersHashMap.put(currentMarker, myMarker);

                //googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MarkerInfoWindowAdapter());
            }
        }
    }
}


public class MapTestAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<MapEntity> mapItems;
    private TextView tvTitle, tvLat, tvLang;

    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public MapTestAdapter(Activity activity,
            List<MapEntity> mapItems ) {
        super();
        this.activity = activity;
        this.mapItems = mapItems;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mapItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mapItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
                    activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map_custom_marker, null);
        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

        tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitleMarker);
        tvLat = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtLatMarker);
        tvLang = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtLangMarker);

        NetworkImageView imageshow = (NetworkImageView) 
                convertView.findViewById(R.id.markerthumnail);

        final MapBerau mb = mapItems.get(position);

        tvTitle.setText(mb.getTitle());
        tvLat.setText(String.valueOf(mb.getLat()));
        tvLang.setText(String.valueOf(mb.getLang()));
        imageshow.setImageUrl(mb.getThumbnail(), imageLoader);

        return convertView;
    }


}
```

Comment: What problem are you getting with this?

Comment: Usually I use volley on ListView, to put list just call setAdapter. but I don't know how to put list to Marker GoogleMap :)

Comment: means you want to show multiple markers on map?

Comment: yes, can you help me? above is purely my code

Comment: to me it seems that you are calling plotmarkers() before you download the data and not after. Remember downloading data will do asynchronous so it will most likely end after you have already called the method plotmarkers. So all you have to do is call plotMarkers(mbList); after you downloaded the data.

Comment: @Dya any error are you getting in it?And yes I will help you.

Comment: Also you are calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); but you are not changing the data in that adapter. Make sure to change the data before calling notifyDataSetChanged(); and I hope you use that adapter somewhere as it seems its not being used.

Comment: @Raykud: I try to rollback position but not fix it.

Comment: @pratt: ExecuteDeliver not response

Comment: @Dya I mean are you getting any error or exception in your logcat?

Comment: @pratt: java.lang.string cannot be cast to java.long.number

Comment: @Dya on which line? Paste that line here.

Comment: @pratt : hi.. the problem has been solved, I'm just put gmap array before looping.. then call marker.. but if you completely as well, may be your have some different logic, kindly to shared with us. Too many believers focus on a problem or its perceived solution instead of making lucky.

Comment: @Dya ya I have post my logic below in my answer, please take a look and see if you found it useful then please accept and upvote the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To place multiple marker try with the code below:

```
private HashMap<Marker, HashMap<String, String>> markerHashMap;
markerHashMap = new HashMap<Marker, HashMap<String, String>>();

//Here, my data format is ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>;
for (int i = 0; i < YOUR DATA.size(); i++) {
                                final HashMap<String, String> mapData = YOURDATA.get(i);
                                if (mapData.get("latitude").trim().length() > 0 && mapData.get("longitude").trim().length() > 0) {
                                    placeMarker(mapData);
                                }
                            }

//placeMarker() method:

private void placeMarker(final HashMap<String, String> mapData) {
private Marker marker;
        try {
            marker=googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(
                    BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.YOUR MARKER IMAGE))).position(
                    new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(mapData.get("latitude")), Double.parseDouble(mapData.get("longitude")))));
            markerHashMap.put(marker, mapData);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```